# Aldryn - DjangoCMS install addons not present in "Manage Addons"

Tags: python, django

I am quite a Django n00b, and figured using Aldryn for my first real django site would be a good idea!

I have successfully installed and implementer `Aldryn News & Blog`.
Now I would like to install [Aldryn Search](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-search) that is not accessible from the "Manage Addons" under the Aldryn control panel.

I very confused on how to install an addon like Aldryn Search that is not accessible from within "Manage Addons". Should I somehow use the "Add custom Addon" and register the package as a new custom addon.

Or should I create a local development environment and somehow install the addon and upload it? (does it exist a tutorial for this?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways in which to install arbitrary Django packages into an Aldryn project.

## The quick, easy way

The easiest, quickest way is simply to place the module(s) you need into the project directory, thus placing them on the Python path. You need then to make sure that your `settings.py`, `urls.py` and so on are appropriately configured. Then you can push these changes to Aldryn itself. This is described in [Adding a new application to your Aldryn project - the quick and easy way](http://support.divio.com/hc/en-us/articles/208204615).

## The create-an-Addon way

A more involved way to do it, that has benefits for long-term use and re-use, is to turn the package into a private or public Aldryn Addon. This is described in [Developing an Addon application for Aldryn](http://support.divio.com/hc/en-us/articles/207504019).

## A middle way

Another way is somewhere between the two. Add the package to the project's `requirements.in` - you can do this in various ways, for example:

```
# standard install from PyPI
some-package==1.2.3  

# install from an archive
https://example.com/some-package1.2.3.tar.gz#egg=some-package==1.2.3  

# install from a GitHub repository
git+http://git@github.com/some-org/some-package.git#egg=some-package==1.2.3
```

You will need to make sure that your `settings.py`, `urls.py` and so on are appropriately configured.

Run `aldryn project update`. This in effect redeploys your project locally, except for:

`docker-compose run --rm web python manage.py migrate` - you need to run any migrations manually, unlike on Aldryn.

Finally, git `add`, `commit` and `push` your changes to your project, and redeploy it on Aldryn.

This method isn't yet documented in the Aldryn support system, but will be soon.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very valid question in my opinion since add-ons are wrapped into an additional directory that makes the django app inside invisible to Django's INSTALLED_APPS.

If you add them to addons-dev they are ignored by git.

A possible solution (even if maybe not the cleanest) would be to unignore addons-dev by adding `!/addons-dev` to the `.gitignore` in the project's root directory and then add `-e /app/addons-dev/aldryn-package-name` to requirements.in (outside the section generated/overwritten by Aldryn). That's what `aldryn project develop aldryn-package-name` does (for the local environment).

Similarly, if you have a git repository that contains the code (like aldryn-search) you would use `-e git+https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-search.git` in `requirements.in`

In case you need to apply changes to the addon code best practise would be forking the original repository and then checking out your fork as per above instructions.